# Cannot access bottle development server

Tags: python, wsgi, bottle

I am trying to run the bottle hello world example:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I run this file and get the following in my command prompt:

```
Bottle v0.12.9 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

However, when I visit http://localhost:8080/hello all I get is the default "Server not found" page for firefox.

Comment: maybe you run antivirus or firewall and it blocks your server.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are you running Firefox on the same system as you are running Bottle?

Comment: I am running it the same machine.

Comment: Interestingly when I use a different server (for example, paste) it works without issue.

run(server='paste',host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)

Comment: Have you tried to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`? `Localhost` is an internal host which redirects to `127.0.0.1`. So depending on the OS you're working on the needed entry in the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) might not be available.

Comment: Yes neither 127 or localhost work. It seems to be an issue only with the development server included in bottle. When I use a different server backend the page loads without issue.

Comment: Try killall -9 python and try again.

Comment: Does `run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)` work?

Comment: worked for me. Thanks